# Concatenation with shift operator on concatenated array

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am relatively new to SystemVerilog, and I have come across a statement as follows:

```
module Foo (
    output logic [65:0] data_out;
);
logic [65:0] block;

// do stuff 

assign data_out = {<<{block[65:0]}};
endmodule
```

I cannot find any description of the use of the `<<` operator within the concatenation as in the `assign data_out = ...` line above.

Opening up ModelSim and simulating the following dummy code,

```
module test_module;
  logic [7:0] data = 8'b11110000;
  logic [7:0] data_out;
  initial begin

    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i+=1) begin
        $display("data[%0d] = %b", i, data[i]);
    end

    assign data_out = {<<{data[7:0]}};
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i+=1) begin
        $display("data_out[%0d] = %b", i, data_out[i]);
    end

    $finish;
  end
endmodule
```

I see the reported output:

```
# data[0] = 0
# data[1] = 0
# data[2] = 0
# data[3] = 0
# data[4] = 1
# data[5] = 1
# data[6] = 1
# data[7] = 1
# data_out[0] = 1
# data_out[1] = 1
# data_out[2] = 1
# data_out[3] = 1
# data_out[4] = 0
# data_out[5] = 0
# data_out[6] = 0
# data_out[7] = 0
```

It seems that the `{<<{...}}` line has somehow swapped the endianness of the `data` array. Is the behavior of the `{<<{...}}` syntax described somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax is described in the IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 11.4.14 *Streaming operators (pack/unpack)*.  The general form is:

```
{ stream_operator [ slice_size ] stream_concatenation }
```

In your code:

- `stream_operator` is `<<`
- `slice_size` is not specified
- `stream_concatenation` is the expression `{data[7:0]}`

In section 11.4.14.2 *Re-ordering of the generic stream*,

> The slice_size determines the size of each block, measured in bits. If
> a slice_size is not specified, the default is 1.

In your case, the size is 1.  There is an example which is similar to your case:

```
{ << { 8'b0011_0101 }} // generates stream 'b1010_1100 (bit reverse)
```

Thus, your code does a bit reverse.