# Copying Queues to Dynamic Arrays

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl

```
module queues;

  bit [7:0] a[$];

  bit [7:0] d_array[];  

initial begin
  for (int i=0; i<140; i++) 
  a.push_back(i);
  
  a.push_back(140);
  
  a.push_front(144);
  
  foreach(a[i]) $display("\tValue of a[%0d]=%0d",i , a[i]);

  $display("----- Queue size is %0d  -----",a.size());

end
  
  initial begin

    d_array = { >> {a}};
    
    $display(" Dynamic array = %0p ", d_array);
  end

  
endmodule
```

Error: design.sv:19: sorry: Streaming concatenation not supported.
Exit code expected: 0, received:

1. I want to copy my queue 'a' into dynamic array and print it.
2. Next, I want to copy my dynamic array into another queue (b).
3. Then copy this queue (b) partially into queue (c) and print it and implement "Access Random queue Entry".

Comment: You are using Icarus Verilog which has very limited support for SystemVerilog. Use another simulator.

Comment: Thanks dave, it worked with other simulator.

Comment: I wonder how Dave knew you used Icarus? Good question though

Comment: @ShashankVM http://www.edaplayground.com

Comment: Hi @dave_59, can you please explain what this line of code does:  d_array = { >> {a}};

Comment: That's a separate question, already answered [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/550133/concatenation-with-shift-operator-on-concatenated-array/550136#550136). BTW, that syntax is  unnecessary; they could have written `d_array = a;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @dave_59 said, the problem is due to using a simulator in which the function is not supported.

Reading the error message gives us a hint:

> Error: design.sv:19: sorry: Streaming concatenation not supported. Exit code expected: 0, received:

The first error is on line 19, and the error message is "Streaming concatenation not supported". This suggests that the line of code might be valid in SystemVerilog, but is not supported on that simulator.